# Conditional formatting to highlight the whole row if a cell is left blank

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Could anyone tell me please how to highlight a row if the first cell in that row is missing a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the 'Conditional Formatting Rules Manager' (Conditional Formatting->Manage Rules).
2. Click 'New Rule' and choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
3. In the "Format values where this formula is true:" box, enter the cell which you want to check if blank.
4. Place a dollar sign in front of the letter of the cell reference to make it affect only that row, not the whole table or just the cell.
5. Type `=""` at the end of the box to check for if the cell is blank.
6. Click "Format..." and go to the "Fill" tab to choose a colour to fill the row if true and click "OK".
7. Click "Okay" to close the 'New Rule' dialog.
8. Change the "Applies to" value of the rule you just created to the scope of the entire table to make the rule apply to it.  (If your table has a reference name, you can enter it here)
9. Click "Okay to close the 'Conditional Formatting Rules Manager'.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/

Comment: Regarding Step 5 of njallam answer.
Could use =ISBLANK("first cell of the applied to table without $") eg =ISBLANK(A2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the range starts at A2 (e.g. A2:AA20) then use a custom formula and lock the column you're evaluating with the `$` as shown in the examples below.

Either of these will work:

- `=ISBLANK($A2)`
- `=$A2=""`